# How to make the space from the text of the button to its bottom edge independent of the length of the text? (Android)

Tags: android, xml, button

There are buttons that use the custom style. The distance from the text of the button to its bottom edge differs depending on the length of the text - in case the text is transferred to the second and more lines, the distance to the edge is significantly reduced. Is there a way to somehow make these distances the same? Both buttons are in the LinearLayout. Also i use Calligraphy lib to set custom fonts.
[This picture describes the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWUfx.jpg)

Buttons in Layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_in_text"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="short text"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_in_text"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="Very long text. The longes text that you saw before"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />
```

btn_in_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Tried to use

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
```

and

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
```

but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very short answer: add this attribute to both of your `<Button>` tags:

```
    android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Because you're using `<Buttton>` instead of `<TextView>`, you are getting all of the default styles applied to Buttons by the android framework. One of these is a minimum height. That minimum height, combined with your `gravity` attribute including `center_vertical`, means that your text will float in the middle of the button until your text is long enough that it wraps enough times to exceed the button's default height.

Another possible solution is to use `<TextView>` tags instead of Buttons, and remove the `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` attribute. This will also let you remove `android:textAllCaps="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure about the specifics of your problem but I had a similar problem where my textsize was changing the button's size as well and fixed it using

`android:baselineAligned="false"`

In the layout which carries the Buttons since by default the bottom edge of all the text in a row is at the same height.

Here is the link of my solved problem which includes a picture similar to yours :-
[In XML Button size changes with its Font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337745/in-xml-button-size-changes-with-its-font-size)

If that doesn't work try making a fixed button height instead of wrap_content.